# Fragment: overwrite activities margin

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have an Activity container for several different fragments. All fragments should have the same margin except one. This should has no margin. But how can I do that?

This is my **activity_container.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp" />
```

All fragments within this container have a margin of 15dp. But there is one fragment, that should have 0 dp. The fragment have to be in the container. So creating a container only for this fragment is no option. Do somebody has an idea to solve that problem?

Comment: what you can do is remove margin form activity layout and add padding to fragment layout :)

Comment: Make that one fragment to fullscreen, may be it will help you. Using `YourFragment.getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragments cannot be displayed outside of their container, just as with any other view.

Your only option is to remove the margin from your relative layout and add it back as padding onto the individual fragment layouts